# How do I split a data set into train and test sets using

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

I have the following matrices for training a model:

###### INPUT FEATURES MATRIX

$$ X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
| & | & & |\\
X_1 & X_2 & ... & X_m\\
| & | & & |
\end{bmatrix};
~ X.shape = (n_x, m)
$$

###### OUTPUT MATRIX

$$
Y =
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & ... & y_m
\end{bmatrix}
~ ; ~ Y.shape=(1,m)
$$

And I want to split into train and test data sets using `scikitlearn`.

This is what I have tried:

```
>>> print(X.shape)
>>> print(X.dtype)
>>> print(type(X))
>>> print(Y.shape)
>>> print(Y.dtype)
>>> print(type(Y))

(16, 504)
float64
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1, 504)
float64
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
```

But I get the following error:

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2114         raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))
   2115 
-> 2116     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
   2117 
   2118     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    235         else:
    236             result.append(np.array(X))
--> 237     check_consistent_length(*result)
    238     return result
    239 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    209     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
    212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    213 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [16, 1]
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The sample size should be on the first axis. i.e.*

$X.shape = (m, n_x) $

$Y.shape = (m, 1) $

You can simply transpose the data.